# Sketch3: where is the reflection tool?

Tags: sketch-app

The document here: http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/08-styling/7-reflection.html mentioned the "reflection" tool, but it doesn't tell where it is, and I can't find it.

So where is it?

Comment: Where is it in 3.2.2? If you open an older document that had a reflection effect applied, the option appears, but you can't see to add reflection to a new element or layer. Frustrating... help.

Comment: It was removed recently.

Comment: I use sketch 3, and there's no refliection tool.

Comment: Look at the `Flip` control at the top of the right panel.

Answer (score 0):

Select a shape and you can adjust all kinds of fun things (including reflection) via the *Inspector*.

[image: reflection]

Comment: Which version of Sketch are you using, mine is 3.2.2 and there is no reflection in the inspector when I select a shape layer.

Comment: Oops, I'm on 3.1.